# Prevent iCloud Drive from removing specific folders

Tags: mac, icloud, macos, data-synchronization

I'd like to use iCloud Drive to sync my documents + desktop.

However, many times it will remove projects while I'm still working on them (even small ones, like 10MB).

Is there some sort of flag that will tell macOS to sync a folder, but never remove it until I say so?

Mind that I wouldn't like to *not sync* a certain folder, I'd like to *keep macOS from removing it* to create purgeable space.

Comment: Is using iCloud Drive a requirement or can you use something like Dropbox or Google Drive?

Comment: iCloud allows me to save disk space, while other solutions don't. Not that it works that well, unfortunately... :-/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of macOS Sierra 10.12.4, it is [not possible](https://support.apple.com/HT207236) to flag individual folders to stay on your local drive at all times. This is an all-or-nothing toggle.

You may access it under **** → **System Preferences** → **iCloud** → **iCloud Drive Options…** There, uncheck `Optimize Mac Storage`.

This will prevent your files/folders backed by iCloud from being purged automatically from the local storage.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same on iOS and iPadOS?

Comment: For macOS Big Sur to access `Optimise Mac Storage` head to  → System Preferences → Apple ID → Click on iCloud in the sidebar → uncheck `Optimise Mac Storage`. As soon as you do so, it will start pulling everything from the cloud. For me this is very good as I have 2 TB drive and I want my Time Machine backups to include everything I have within my `Documents`.

Comment: The issue I have is iCloud tries to then download absolutely everything, even after I select "Remove Download" on a large number of files, filling up my local hard drive

Answer (score 4):

You can add '.nosync' to any file/folder name to prevent syncing. The element will only be saved in your local harddrive. (Works in Sierra, High Sierra, maybe other versions...not confirmed)

Comment: Oh, great! I wonder why it's not documented...

Comment: Found a link that mentions it: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html under `A User’s iCloud Storage Is Limited`

Comment: Well this also prevents the folder from being backed up to iCloud Drive altogether. The pain point from OP is addressed but a new one is created.